# How to make searchbar filter items?

Tags: angular, ionic2

so I am trying to make the searchbar filter out the items (item1, item2 and item3)

This is my current code, and typing stuff into the searchbar does nothing.

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the ContactusPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contactus',
  templateUrl: 'contactus.html',
})
export class ContactusPage {
items: Array<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setItems();
  }

  setItems() {
    this.items = [ 
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
    'item 3'

    ];
  }

        filterItems(ev: any) {
    this.setItems();
    let val = ev.value;

    if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ContactusPage');
  }

}
```

Please help me see what I am missing out for the filterItems method. I am quite new to ionic so I am not that sure. This is what I got from Ionic repository.

```
  <ion-searchbar placeholder="Filter Items with Cancel" showCancelButton color="danger" (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: Where are you calling filterItems? Could you please add your template code, the mistake may be there.

Comment: <ion-searchbar placeholder="Filter Items with Cancel" showCancelButton color="danger" (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>

Comment: try replacing `(ionInput)` with `(keypress)` or `(input)` more information about supported events is [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/)

Comment: neither of them does any difference, it seems to be a problem with the method instead

Comment: it's two things sorry - I have posted an answer with the details and a live example

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are binding to the `(ionInput)` event and incorrectly assigning `val`

You should instead bind to `(input)` (You can see the list of supported events [in the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/))

**template**

```html
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Filter Items with Cancel" 
  showCancelButton color="danger" 
  (input)="filterItems($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

The `$event` doesn't have a `value` property but I think you were trying to use `srcElement.value` - you can inspect the parameter by logging it to the console at the start of the method to debug this in future.

**component**

```js
filterItems(ev: any) {
  console.log(ev);
  let val = ev.srcElement.value;

  if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
      return item.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

You can see a live example of this working [here on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cm0caYDWOBsnjYL2cCkS?p=preview)

**Edit**

Although this *should* fix your problem I recommend you instead use the method described in [this blog post](https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/) mentioned in [JGFMKs comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468919/how-to-make-searchbar-filter-items#comment77899766_45468919)

This uses `[(ngModel)]="searchTerm"` to bind the data and an Observable with debounce: `searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime` to filter, but not for every key press as in the example I have posted.